# Recode multiple columns in dataframe R

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, recode

I am trying to convert a Y into a 1 for a number of columns that could change (e.g. it could go up to x20).

An example of the data is below as well as an expected output.

```
Data <- tibble(Date = seq.Date(as.Date('2019-01-01'),as.Date('2019-01-08'), by = "day"), 
               x1 = c("Y","","","Y","Y","","Y","Y"),
               x2 = c("","Y","Y","Y","Y","","Y","Y"))


Data_output <- tibble(Date = seq.Date(as.Date('2019-01-01'),as.Date('2019-01-08'), by = "day"), 
               x1 = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1),
               x2 = c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
Data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("x")),~case_when(.=="Y" ~1,
                                           .=="" ~0))
```

or as suggested by @akrun simply:

```
Data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("x")), ~as.integer(.=="Y"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Date          x1    x2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01     1     0
2 2019-01-02     0     1
3 2019-01-03     0     1
4 2019-01-04     1     1
5 2019-01-05     1     1
6 2019-01-06     0     0
7 2019-01-07     1     1
8 2019-01-08     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks was trying to do this but was using funs.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
Data[-1] <- +( Data[-1] == "Y")
```